# XCode 15.0.1 can't connect my real device IOS 17.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode15, ios17

Waiting to reconnect to Jawkhaa Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprep Code: -10 Recovery Suggestion: Previous preparation error: An error occurred while communicating with a remote process.. The connection was invalidated. User Info: {     DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-25 09:53:53 +0000";     DVTReco

Manage run detinations > Previous preparation error: An error occurred while communicating with a remote process.. The connection was invalidated.

my xcode some ios 16 device already can connect. Buy still can't connect ios 17 device

im already searched google & apple developer sites can't find this solution how to solve it SOMEONE HELP ME PLS

Comment: it's not beta. ios 17.1 is legal version. How to downgrade IOS version 17 to unsigned version someone tell me.

Answer (score -3):

Upgrading to macOS Sonoma solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).